# Fast glob sync returning empty array when used with api endpoint

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob

I am calling `fg.sync(globPatterns, { cwd : someWD }` to get files in a directory. but it returns an empty array. Running `fg.sync('*')` does return a result however.

I logged the pattern and the wd and took the exact params and ran it in a node repl. which returned the result I wanted. Somehow it just doesnt work inside an api endpoint. (I am using fastify)

Also possibly `process.cwd()` is modified probably because of other shelljs commands, but the cwd I am passing is an absolute path.

I am testing on Windows. I suspect its an issue with me being on windows, or some permissions issue. I am passing the paths in posix format, and it works in a node repl so I dont think it could be the first one.

Anything to do with typescript maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `{cwd: __dirname, root: __dirname}` to avoid all path issues so you can be sure it's always executing from that particular file.  You can't rely on `cwd`.

Comment: I am calling fast-glob like
`fg.snyc(['src/*', 'index.html'], { cwd: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER, root: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER }` where the path is in posix format, it still returns an empty array in my node env. Although it works correctly in the node repl. which is totally confusing for me.

Comment: Also sorry for the late response, was blocked by another bug.

Comment: Ah okay.  Then all I can think if the asterisk is working is that the glob pattern you're using isn't correct.  Did you try '/absolute/path/**/*', the '**/*' part is to match all files, or you can do '**/*.ts' or whatever.  Maybe it's the pattern itself.

Comment: Also instead of using an absolute path on the 'cwd', instead just use ````glob.sync('**/*.ts', {cwd: __dirname})```` so that it executes from the file that's calling it.  Sorry my previous message ````*```` was wiped out because of not making it code, didn't realize.  I was saying use ````**/*```` or ````**/*.ts````.

Comment: fast glob should match files, `fg.sync('*')` works `fg.sync('*", { cwd: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER, root: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER })` doesnt work. 

However all these work, if I use in a node repl session, which is if I type node in a shell.

I am not using glob, but fast glob instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin.  1. Make sure the pattern you're using is actually correct (I don't ever use absolute path, just __dirname with the pattern for that file).  2.  Make sure that you're not getting backslash paths on windows, "Always use forward-slashes in glob expressions (patterns and ignore option). Use backslashes for escaping characters." -> from their documentation.  3. Try and use ````#! /usr/bin/env node```` in your shell (no idea if it'll make a difference).  Otherwise I have no clue.

Comment: Thats the thing I am using posix path, and it runs fine on node repl, but not inside node code.